# Reading asterisk character (*) from a file in bash

Tags: bash

I am taking lines from a .txt file:
Say Input.txt

```
a
*
b
```

Then I am reading it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1

ans=0
while  read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
echo $line
done < $file # passing the file
```

for which I am getting the following output

```
a
test main.py sic.sh
b
```

Where files of my directory are being shown instead of *

I want to take some decisions on the basis of * char for which I need to detect/read * ?

Comment: The **input** is fine. The **output** is a problem. Make it `echo "$line"` and you're fine.

Comment: BTW, this is a bug that http://shellcheck.net/ would catch automatically.

Comment: always quote variables to prevent wordsplitting and to prevent issues with globbing

Comment: See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always quote variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"

ans=0
while  read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "$line"
done < "$file" # passing the file
```